# reset meta viewport to adapt mobile phone

Tags: html, css

I'm setting the meta viewport of the webpage `<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`, then reset it.

```
var winWidths    = (document.body) && (document.body.clientWidth) ? document.body.clientWidth : window.innerWidth;
var defaultWidth = 750;
var viewport     = document.getElementById('viewport');
var appScale     = winWidths >= defaultWidth ? 1 : (winWidths / defaultWidth);
viewport.content = 'width=device-width,initial-scale=' + appScale + ', minimum-scale=' + appScale + ', maximum-scale=' + appScale;
```

that's work success. I can use `px` on mobile page. No need to calculate rem. But...
Some times, between two `img` or `background` will show a white line, like this: [image]

and that's my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div><img src="./timg.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="./timg.jpeg"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style>
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

how to fix it and why?